# Upload Build artifacts from Jenkins Pipeline to Sharepoint

Tags: jenkins, sharepoint, jenkins-pipeline

I have a requirement to upload the build artifacts to SharePoint at the end of the build. using jenkins pipeline.

I didn't find any plugin to achieve this.

My Jenkins instance is running on a Linux machine. Please suggest the best way to achieve this

Comment: i'm geussing that you are referring to some custom spfx app code that gets built, and not something like a remote event receiver?

Comment: also could you please specify which version of sharepoint ? [Online, 2019, 2016]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using CLI for Microsoft 365 for this (available for linux as well). Looks somewhat like this:

```
m365 login --authType password --userName user@contoso.com --password pass@word1

m365 spo file add --webUrl https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/project-x --folder 'Shared Documents' --path 'C:\MS365.jpg'
```

https://pnp.github.io/cli-microsoft365/cmd/login/

https://pnp.github.io/cli-microsoft365/cmd/spo/file/file-add/

You may need to add special account to your sharepoint for your jenkins, or add an [app password](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/using-app-passwords-with-apps-that-don-t-support-two-step-verification-5896ed9b-4263-e681-128a-a6f2979a7944) to be able to upload file from a daemon process (if your sharepoint requires MFA authentication)

Comment: Is there a way to pass SharePoint user credentials in the CLI? Or pass some authentication Token?

Comment: Yes or course. I have appended the example. But basically take a look at the CLI docs above.